# Unable to make user defined function call in Polymer

Tags: javascript, polymer-3.x

I'm implementing my website using **Polymer 3.0**. I'm creating buttons in **javascript**. And I want to call user defined function on-click of the button.

I have tried adding event listener but the function is getting invoked as soon as the page is loaded.
I have tried calling the function in bu.onclick function but the function is not getting invoked

//My code below

```
import { PolymerElement, html } from "./node_modules/@polymer/polymer/polymer-element.js";

class MyPage extends PolymerElement {
  static get template() {
    return html`
           <!-- Some useful div elements -->
           <iron-ajax 
                auto
                url= // my url
                handle-as="json"
                on-response="response"
                on-error="_statusFailed"
                last-error="{{lastError}}"
                last-response="{{lastResponse}}"
                debounce-duration="300">
        </iron-ajax>
     `;
}

constructor()
{
    super(); 
}

response()
{
    let list = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('#list');
    let bu = document.createElement('button');

    bu.onclick=function()
    {
        let a= this.value;
        console.log('Button Value: '+a);
        this.buttonprocessor(a);
    };
    list.append(bu);
}

buttonprocessor(msg)
{
    //some code 
}
```

When I click on the button created, I'm getting the following error

```
Uncaught TypeError: this.buttonprocessor is not a function
 at HTMLButtonElement.bu.onclick
```

Thanks beforehand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the error message is pointing to the right direction this.buttonprocessor is not defined. Switch your function with a arrow function and it should be fine cause then this will point to the right class.

```
bu.onclick=() => {
    let a= this.value;
    console.log('Button Value: '+a);
    this.buttonprocessor(a);
};
```

this within a function state always points to the function itself you could also solve this like that:

```
var that = this;
bu.onclick=function()
{
    let a= this.value;
    console.log('Button Value: '+a);
    that.buttonprocessor(a);
};
```